# Have to run same queries against many servers (30+), use CURSOR or LOOP

Tags: sql-server

I have to do the following 30 times

connect to server with unique IP using TSQL
download a table to temp table
do some query on the temp table (same query 30times)

at end union all the tables for a final solution

Would loop or cursor or some other approach be a better approach?  I don't want to copy paste similar SQL 30 times but that is also an option.

I am currently using linked server to connect to each server

Comment: Have you considered a PowerShell script instead of doing it all in T-SQL?

Comment: Is PowerShell alot better than something like Python for working with TSQL?  I know python but not powershell.

Comment: Use any scripting tool you are comfortable with that can execute SQL queries and process results. I mentioned PS because it's already available with Windows and can use .NET framework SqlClient similarly to c# so you don't need to install anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want best performance then using the `UNION ALL` operator 30 times is probably more efficient because it's more relational of a solution than using either a **loop** or **cursor**. If you don't care about performance, then a **loop** will be simpler to implement than a **cursor**.

Though I'm not sure how you plan to dynamically change out which server you're pulling data from in a **loop** or **cursor** unless you're building a [**Dynamic SQL**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) string and then executing at the end, or by **loop** you meant in a procedural language.

Comment: I was thinking of putting in the IP address into a table and somehow loop through that if thats possible, but if you are saying copy pasting 30x is better performance then forget it.

Comment: @bakalolo Even with the IP address in the table, you won't be able to use them to select data from in a SQL **loop** to run the query unless you build a **Dynamic SQL** string and then execute it.

Answer (score 3):

Connecting to other instances without Linked Servers is not convenient unless you use [Registered Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/register-servers?view=sql-server-ver15) or [Central Management Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-a-central-management-server-and-server-group?view=sql-server-ver15).

If you have registered servers or CMS, you can execute the same query against all the instances in a group (or all registered servers) at once via SSMS (see the links above). But I don't know if you can output the results to a single table in one instance; you may be stuck with copy & paste to Excel.

If you're willing to go with Powershell, the [`dbatools`](https://dbatools.io) module has a very convenient solution in [`Invoke-DbaQuery`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Invoke-DbaQuery).

`Invoke-DbaQuery -Query "select fields from table" -SqlInstance instance1,instance2,instance3` will return an object representing the results of the query *plus* a field with the corresponding instance name that each returned record came from.

From there, you can filter the results with `Where-Object`, or you can copy the results into a table in another instance with [`Write-DbaDbDataTable`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Write-DbaDbTableData)

Comment: I am using linked server to connect, I just want to iterate over each IP address using cursor and connect to each using linked server.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what's more important than if you use a cursor or loop -- [they're the same thing, after all](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor) -- are a couple other things:

- Error handling
- Query performance

Error handling, because if you think running the same query on 30 different servers is annoying, having to run the same query 30 times because it keeps failing at different points will be just as bad.

Likewise, no matter how you approach executing the query across your chosen targets: If it runs slowly, any triumph felt from making an initial decision will be quite fleeting. It's bad enough waiting a minute for one query to finish. Multiply that by 30 and, well, I think in math they call it "boring".

Comment: How does try catch sound for error handling with cursor and procedure to connect to each server?  I would like to ideally skip over failed connection and print a message or something.

Answer (score 0):

Is exactly for this scenario that I wrote the tool [QueryLauncher](https://github.com/francesco1119/QueryLauncher)

Is written in `PowerShell`.

Basically your drop all your `.sql` files in a folder and **QueryLauncher** will run those for you.